# Notations: double differentials in different scenarios

Tags: calculus, notation, differential

Many of you may be familiar with the equation for the magnetic force between two thin wire elements carrying electric currents:

$$d^2\vec{F} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{I_1 \, d\vec{\ell}_1 \times \left( I_2 \, d\vec{\ell}_2 \times \hat{r} \right)}{r^2}$$

or, regarding the currents and separation as constants,

$$d^2 F \propto d\ell_1 \, d\ell_2 \tag{1}$$

Similarly the magnetic flux through a surface is modeled by

$$\Phi = \iint \vec B \cdot d\vec A$$

where it is understood that

$$dA = dx \, dy \tag{2}$$

My question is: Why is the left-hand side of equation $\left( 1 \right)$ marker with “$d^2$” while the left-hand side of equation $\left( 2 \right)$ is marked with just “$d$”?

Comment: Well the $\mathrm{d}l$'s are separate distinct quantities that contribute to the force because one wire produces the field that the other wire feels. Meanwhile the area example is entirely different, area is length by width, the length isn't setting up something for the width to feel. That is you don't have to integrate the length to determine whats happening to the width. In the force you have to perform the inner integral first to have a field to integrate over, so its $d(d F) = d^2 F$ not $dF dF$

Comment: Okay, @Triatticus .  In practice, how could I know whether to use a single or a double differential?

Comment: I would just avoid this notation more or less all together save for when encountered in particle physics as in $\mathrm{d}^n x$ which stands for the $4n$ (x typically a $4$-vector) phase space integral. I personally have never written the magnetic force this way or have seen it written this way.

Comment: @Triatticus That’s exactly how it appears in the SI brochure

Comment: I mean as a PhD student I have never seen it written that way by either my colleague or my advisor.