# What is meant by $d(x,y)$ in Fubini’s theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

According to [*Wolfram MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html), Fubini’s theorem takes a multiple integral over a region $R=\{(x,y):x\in[a,b]\wedge y\in[c,d]\}$ and turns it into an iterated integral by the relationship

$$\iint_Rf(x,y)\,d(x,y)=\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$

I have never seen the differential $d(x,y)$ before. Normally, I see something of the nature $dA=dx\,dy$.

Could someone explain what $d(x,y)$ means and whence it came?

Comment: The short answer is: $\iint_{R}(\bullet)\,d(x,y)$ is the integral with respect to the product measure of $\Bbb R^2$. Do you know what this means?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No, but I will certainly research it.  Thomas M Berndt also brought that up in his answer.  It seems reminiscent of a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, $dA$, $d(x,y)$, $dxdy$ are all the same thing. It is actually better to write $dA$ or $d(x,y)$ in general to avoid confusion. But some authors write $dA = dxdy$.

If you know measure theory, $\int f(x,y) \, d(x,y)$ means integration with respect to the product measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. $d(x,y)$ is the differential of the product measure.

You can also think about it in terms of Riemman integration (if you prefer that to measure theory). I recommend Chapter 14 of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis. It has an excellent treatment of Riemann integration in multiple variables. Let me give you some idea here:

Think of cutting $R$ up into $m$ rectangles. Let $\Delta A_i$ be the area of the $i$-th rectangle. Pick a sample point $(x_i^{\ast},y_i^{\ast})$ in each rectangle. If $f$ is positive, the volume trapped by the graph $z=f(x,y)$ above $R$ is approximately
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m} f(x_i^{\ast},y_i^{\ast}) dA_i.
$$ 
If $f$ is not always positive, this sum represents a signed volume (just like a signed area in 1-D Calculus). If we take an appropriate limit as $m \to \infty$, we obtain the integral 
\begin{align}\label{1}\tag{1}
\int_R f(x,y) dxdy = \int_R f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_R f(x,y) dA = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{m} f(x_i^{\ast},y_i^{\ast}) \Delta A_i.  
\end{align}

On the other hand, the interated integral in terms of Riemann sums is 
\begin{align}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\int_{c}^{d} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) dxdy 
&= \int_{c}^{d} \left( \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) dx \right) dy
= \int_{c}^{d} \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f(x_j^{\ast},y) \Delta x \right) dy \\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f(x_j^{\ast},y_k^{\ast}) \Delta x \right) \Delta y.
\end{align}
Fubini's theorem is saying that these two expressions ((1) and (2)) are equal under certain conditions.

Comment: Wow! I finally understand why I sometimes seen $\int dA$ and other times see $\iint dA$! Would you like to try to answer [“Notation: double differentials in different scenarios”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297071/notations-double-differentials-in-different-scenarios) as well? I think you definitely could.

Comment: Regarding [“Notation: double differentials in different scenarios”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297071/notations-double-differentials-in-different-scenarios), I agree with the comments by @Triatticus. I think the superscript 2 in $d^2F$ is just a notation chosen to emphasize that there is a double integral involved.  I would tend to use $dF$ as a notation instead, but I can see why someone might want to use $d^2F$ for emphasis.